# Concatenating variable with jquery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, concatenation

I have a variable:

```
var MAX_OFFERS_TO_SHOW = 3;
```

And I want to use this variable as `index` for the jquery `:lt()` selector

```
$("div.notspecialoffer:lt()").slideDown();
```

How will I concatenate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
$("div.notspecialoffer:lt("+ MAX_OFFERS_TO_SHOW+")").slideDown();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `+`**(Concat) operator** as shown below:-

```
$("div.notspecialoffer:lt("+ MAX_OFFERS_TO_SHOW +")").slideDown();
```